# Joining two subqueries with union all and join leads to suboptimal execution plan

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan

I've faced the similar problem on my production environment, but I managed to reproduce this behavior on [Northwind DB](https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com).

Consider the following query:

```
USE NORTHWND; 
DECLARE @ids TABLE ( Id NCHAR(50) );
INSERT  INTO @ids
VALUES  ( N'AROUT' ),
        ( N'ALFKI' );

SELECT  *
FROM    ( SELECT    c.CustomerID
          FROM      dbo.Customers c
          WHERE     c.CustomerID IN ( SELECT    Id
                                      FROM      @ids )
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    '0'
        ) t1
JOIN    ( SELECT    o.CustomerID
          FROM      dbo.Orders o
          --LEFT JOIN dbo.[Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
          UNION ALL
          SELECT    '0'
        ) t2 ON t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID
OPTION  ( RECOMPILE );
```

It has pretty good query plan:
[image: Good plan]

Now when I uncomment line with `LEFT JOIN`, the plan becomes not as good (seems like query processor can't push the `CustomerID` filter to the data access operators):
[image: Bad plan]

When I add `FORCESEEK` hint on `dbo.Orders`, query processor can't produce a query plan. 
On the other hand, when I remove one of the `UNION ALL`, the query plan becomes as good as the first one.

Is that expected behavior? Why does the query processor not put filter by `CustomerID` before the join operator?

Comment: What's the reason behind this weird `UNION ALL SELECT    '0'` ?

Comment: @ypercube no real reason in this example - tried to simplify it as far as possible. In original query more complex `UNION ALL` was generated by the ORM (Entity Framework)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that SQL Server simply does not have the appropriate optimization rules to yield the seek-into-`Orders` query that you are looking for in the case of a `UNION ALL` on both sides of the query. Such a query plan is theoretically possible, but the query optimizer is not capable of producing it for your query.

In order to reach this conclusion, I compared the full original query (including the `LEFT JOIN`) to an alternate formulation of the query that yields a much lower estimated cost (`0.042` vs. `0.085`). So SQL Server would be likely to choose this lower cost alternative if it were able to explore this plan shape for your query.

**The original query plan**

Here is the original plan, with an estimated cost of `0.085`.

[image]

**The alternate query plan**

This query is semantically equivalent to the original query but has an estimated cost of `0.042`, about half the cost. It is formed by promoting the second UNION ALL up to the top-level of the query. This requires us to reference `t1` (the set of customers) twice, but even so yields a plan with half the cost by allowing seeks into the `Orders` and `[Order Details]` tables.

[image]

**The alternate query**

Here is the full query you can use to play around with this approach:

```
DECLARE @ids TABLE ( Id NCHAR(50) );
INSERT  INTO @ids
VALUES  ( N'AROUT' ),
        ( N'ALFKI' );

-- Define the original t1 as a CTE 
WITH customers AS (
    SELECT    c.CustomerID
    FROM      dbo.Customers c
    WHERE     c.CustomerID IN ( SELECT    Id
                                FROM      @ids )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT    '0'
)
-- Join t1 to the top half of the original UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM Customers t1
JOIN ( SELECT    o.CustomerID
          FROM      dbo.Orders o
          LEFT JOIN dbo.[Order Details] od ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
        ) t2 ON t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID
-- And then join it again to the bottom half of the original UNION ALL
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM Customers t1
JOIN ( SELECT    '0' AS CustomerId ) t2 ON t2.CustomerID = t1.CustomerID
OPTION  ( RECOMPILE);
```

**Takeaways / caveats**

- In general, I have found that `Concatenation` operators are good at getting in the way of the query optimizer and preventing it from yielding an optimal plan. A couple examples include [this Connect issue where `UNION ALL` prevents optimized bitmap filters](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/974909) as well as repeated observations that `Concatenation` operators, particularly if nested, fool the SQL 2012 and earlier Cardinality Estimator and may yield sub-optimal plans due to poor cardinality estimates. Obviously `UNION ALL` is a very useful tool, but it's worth being aware that it does occasionally limit the query optimizer's ability to optimize your query.
- Actually splitting the query into two separate units in this way might or might not make sense on your real use case, but it could be worth a try. (This particular query benefits from the fact that one of the two chunks can be simplified since it contains only the dummy `SELECT '0'`.)
- The data sets involved on `Northwind` are so small that it's difficult to draw conclusions, so testing with your real world data set will be important.

Comment: Thank you for explanation and workaround! Should I post another issue on Connect? :)

Comment: You are welcome to; I'm not too optimistic that it would be addressed, but you never know and it's good to provide feedback for the SQL team even if they can't address all of it. I think it's probably going to be necessary to do the query re-write if you want such a plan though.

Answer (score 2):

They give different results, and the QO is coming up with the best option based on what it knows.

When you join to OrderDetails, it will give a higher number of rows. So the engine needs to filter Orders to the customers, and do a join with OrderDetails to work out how many rows are needed. As a Merge Join is quick, and it doesn't know how many rows to expect in the table variable, it figures that the best thing to do is complete the join to OrderDetails first, and then complete a Hash Match.

But I would also be checking that NCHAR(50) is the right type to use. And use N'0' if that's appropriate.

And I would look into whether or not the UNION ALL values are actually needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The question was more about research QO beahvior in this specific case.

Comment: AFAIK, cardinality of table variable is always estimated as 1

Comment: For the purposes of "how many rows are going to come out of a scan", yes. But it doesn't know how likely a row is to be found in there. It chooses to check the table for every row that comes out of Customers. If it knew there were actually only one row in the table variable, it would've pulled that out first, and then searched through Customers. And of course, the same row could be in the table variable twice because you don't have a PK on it. These would affect your plan too.

Comment: Hm. With  `c.CustomerID  = N'AROUT'` it has the similar plan. The interesting part for me is that when I do any step away (e.g. removing `JOIN`, `UNION ALL`), QO works as expected...

Comment: With all those elements, the cheaper plan has the Hash Match. You could con it, but the maths based on what it knows cause that plan to be chosen.

Comment: @RobFarley The cheapest plan (that I've been able to find) is actually the loop plan that the OP suspected would be optimal; its estimated cost is half that of the plan SQL Server chooses. It's just that SQL Server isn't capable of producing this plan without a minor re-write of the query.